# Derivative of Dirac distribution in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Consider the Dirac delta distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

For an exercise I need to calculate the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x,y) $ and
$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\delta(x,y)$

Let $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta(x,y))  \phi(x,y)\, dx\,dy$

Using polar coordinates I get

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} ( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \delta(r) ) \phi(r,\alpha)\, dr\,d\alpha=\delta(0)\phi(0,0)-\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \delta(r) \partial_r \phi(r,\alpha)\,dr\,d\alpha$

I am not really sure on how to Continue

Comment: Your transition to polar-coordinates doesn't seem right to me, however changing coordinates here is non-sense anyway. Integrate by parts.

Comment: @Tobsn Integrating by parts leads me to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta(x,y) \phi (x,y))dxdy=  -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x,y) \partial_x \phi (x,y)dxdy$

Comment: What kind of answer is expected? Is it how $\partial_x\delta(x,y)$ acts on $\phi,$ i.e.
$$\langle \partial_x\delta(x,y), \phi(x,y) \rangle = -\langle \delta(x,y), \partial_x\phi(x,y) \rangle = -\partial_x\phi(0,0)$$

Comment: @md2perpe The exact question is to calculate the gradient of the diract detla

Comment: Without it being said in what form the answer should be? Or is it obvious from the context that it should be in terms of $\phi$?
$$\langle \nabla\delta, \phi \rangle = -\langle \delta, \nabla\phi \rangle = -\nabla\phi(\mathbf{0})$$

Comment: @md2perpe There is no context to it. It is just calculate the gradient of the dirac delta. But I assume it should be in terms of $\phi$

Comment: @md2perpe So if I understood it correct,  $\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty}\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial \delta(x,y)}{\partial dx} \\\frac{\partial \delta(x,y)}{\partial dy}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  \phi_1(x,y)\\\phi_2(x,y)\end{pmatrix}dxdy=$
$\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty}\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty}  \frac{\partial \delta(x,y)}{\partial dx} \phi_1(x,y)+\frac{\partial \delta(x,y)}{\partial dy} \phi_2(x,y)dxdy$

Comment: Calculating gives $\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty}  \frac{\partial \delta(x,y)}{\partial dx} \phi_1(x,y)dx=-\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty} \delta(x,y)\frac{\partial \phi_1(x,y)}{\partial dx} dx$ by Integration by parts.

Comment: So summarized I get
$\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty}\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty}  \frac{\partial \delta(x,y)}{\partial dx} \phi_1(x,y)+\frac{\partial \delta(x,y)}{\partial dy} \phi_2(x,y)dxdy=$
$\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty}\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty}  -\delta(x,y)\frac{\partial \phi_1(x,y)}{\partial dx} -  \delta(x,y)\frac{\partial \phi_2(x,y)}{\partial dx}dxdy=$
$\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty}\int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty} -\begin{pmatrix} \delta(x,y)\\\delta(x,y)\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  \frac{\partial \phi_1(x,y)}{\partial dx} \\\frac{\partial \phi_2(x,y)}{\partial dy}\end{pmatrix}dxdy$

Comment: Thus $\langle \nabla \delta, \phi \rangle=-\langle  \delta,\nabla \phi \rangle$

Comment: You don't need to take $\phi$ to be a vector. That just makes things confusing and strange. Just take $\phi$ to be a scalar.

Comment: Thank you very much!